# How to find all possible reachable numbers from a position?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given `2 elements n, s and an array A of size m`, where `s is initial position` which lies between `1 <= s <= n`, our task is to perform m operations to s and in each operation we either make s = s + A[i] or s = s - A[i], and we have to print all the values which are possible after the m operation and all those value should lie between 1 - n (inclusive).

> Important Note: If during an operation we get a value s < 1 or s > n,
>   we don't go further with that value of s.

I solved the problem using BFS, but the problem is BFS approach is not optimal here, can someone suggest any other more optimal approach to me or an algorithm will greatly help.

For example:-

If n = 3, s = 3, and A = {1, 1, 1}

```
                            3
                         /     \
operation 1:           2         4  (we don’t proceed with 4 as it is > n)
                   /   \         /  \
operation 2:     1       3      3    5
                / \     / \    / \   / \
operation 3:   0   2   2   4  2   4  4  6
```

So final values reachable by following above rules are 2 and 2 (that is two times 2). we don't consider the third two as it has an intermediate state which is > n ( same case applicable if < 1).

Comment: Can you confirm that you have referred to `m` and `n` in the right way and not sometimes used the wrong reference? It looks like you have mixed them up at some point.

Comment: i referred them right, tell me where you have confusion?

Comment: What confuses me is that the array's size is `m`, but you are never allowed to access elements above `n`. So if `n < m` then the last items of the array are useless. If `n > m`, then what to do with `s = n` as there is possibly no array element with `n-1`? Also, I don't understand where `i` is coming from in `A[i]`.

Comment: we have m operations and array size was m, in each operation we access the ith value of array (where 0<= i < m (0 based index)), and in each operation we change current s to either s+A[i] or s-A[i], and this s+A[i] should be <=n & s-A[i] should be >= 0.

Comment: I am now even more confused: *array size was one*? Could you provide the code you tried with?

Comment: So basically we're looking for all integers combinations, n1*A[1] + n2*A[2]+...+nk*A[k], that fall within 1 and n? (I didn't bother thinking about whether we can express each such integer combination with your procedure.)

Comment: no, blazs time complexity for above BFS method is O(2^n), i am using above procedure just to express the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this dynamic programming solution, which runs in `O(nm)` time and requires `O(n)` space.

First establish a boolean array called `reachable`, initialize it to `false` everywhere except for `reachable[s]`, which is `true`.

This array now represents whether a number is reachable in `0` steps. Now for every `i` from `1` to `m`, we update the array so that `reachable[x]` represents whether the number `x` is reachable in `i` steps. This is easy: `x` is reachable in `i` steps if and only if either `x - A[i]` or `x + A[i]` is reachable in `i - 1` steps.

In the end, the array becomes the final result you want.

---

EDIT: pseudo-code here.

```
// initialization:
for x = 1 to n:
    r[x] = false
r[s] = true

// main loop:
for k = 1 to m:
    for x = 1 to n:
        last_r[x] = r[x]
    for x = 1 to n:
        r[x] = (last_r[x + A[k]] or last_r[x - A[k]])
```

Here `last_r[x]` is by convention `false` if `x` is not in the range `[1 .. n]`.

If you want to maintain the number of ways that each number can be reached, then you do the following changes:

1. Change the array `r` to an integer array;
2. In the initialization, initialize all `r[x]` to `0`, except `r[s]` to `1`;
3. In the main loop, change the key line to:

   r[x] = last_r[x + A[k]] + last_r[x - A[k]]

Comment: can you please provide a simple pseudo code, i am little confused

Comment: does this code also keep track for the count of a value, like in above example 2 occurs two times.

Comment: @Godfather See my edit. It's just a slight modification, once you understand how it works.

Comment: i think there is a one problem in your solution, in above example we can reach 2 by three ways but we will not consider one two because it comes after the 4 (which is > n).

Comment: @Godfather I assumed that "reaching" means reaching in the end, i.e. after all `m` steps. If you consider all middle steps also as reachable, then just keep another array `s` that accumulates the sum of `r` in every step.

Comment: if i am not asking too much, can you please modify your pseudo code for that too, please.

Comment: i am modified my example please have a look at it.

Comment: @Godfather I see, probably I misunderstood you. The code I gave is OK, it won't count the third `2`. Node that you should consider `last_r[x]` as `0` if `x` is not in the range `[1 .. n]`.

Comment: Okay i will try this code again tomorrow, thanks for your help :)

Comment: okay there is just a one small bug in your i have fixed than, and the code worked like a charm.... :) thanks again